# How can I solve this error that arises when trying to train a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been getting this error while trying to train a model with this architecture. The issue is associated with the input shapes. Can anyone please help me out? The model architecture and the error is attached below

```py
def simple_unet_model(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS, num_classes):
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_DEPTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    s = inputs

    #Contraction path
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(s)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1)(c1)
    c1 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c1)
    
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)
    c2 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c2)
     
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2)(c3)
    c3 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2))(c3)
     
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2)(c4)
    c4 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(c4)
     
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3)(c5)
    c5 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c5)
    
    #Expansive path 
    u6 = Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2)(c6)
    c6 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c6)
     
    u7 = Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2)(c7)
    c7 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c7)
     
    u8 = Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1)(c8)
    c8 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c8)
     
    u9 = Conv3DTranspose(16, (2, 2, 2), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1])
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1)(c9)
    c9 = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer, padding='same')(c9)
     
    outputs = Conv3D(num_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)
     
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    #compile model outside of this function to make it flexible. 
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

Meanwhile the inputs shape of image and mask are `(1,172,128,128,1)` and `(1,172,128,128,4)` respectively. And the types are `float64` and `float32` respectively. The error is as follows:

```
Epoch 1/50

2022-06-03 08:45:27.043299: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-03 08:45:27.776684: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2151 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-06-03 08:45:49.914398: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8101

2022-06-03 08:45:27.043299: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-03 08:45:27.776684: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 2151 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
2022-06-03 08:45:49.914398: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8101
2022-06-03 08:45:55.278696: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 601.00MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-06-03 08:45:55.278748: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 601.00MiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-06-03 08:45:55.289252: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-06-03 08:45:55.289295: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-06-03 08:45:55.302345: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-06-03 08:45:55.302387: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [6] in <cell line: 1>
    history=model.fit(train_img_datagen,

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67 in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:58 in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

    InvalidArgumentError:  ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,128,24,16,16] vs. shape[1] = [1,128,25,16,16]
     [[node model_1/concatenate_4/concat
 (defined at C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:3224)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4350]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_1/concatenate_4/concat:
In[0] model_1/conv3d_transpose_4/BiasAdd (defined at C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py:1660)   
In[1] model_1/conv3d_26/Relu (defined at C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\tf2.7\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4867)    
In[2] model_1/concatenate_4/concat/axis: ...
```

Comment: Looks like a shape mismatch to me.

Comment: Hi, I've included the model I used. Can you help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the shapes of the inputs to the `Concat` layer:

```
ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,128,24,16,16] vs. shape[1] = [1,128,25,16,16]
```

Check the inputs to the `Concat` layer.

Post the model architecture code in the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have added the model used. Can you suggest any way to correct the error now?